# PostgreSQL ltree find all child node of a given path (With out using expression)

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, where-clause, ltree

Only child node of given path (Except the given path)

Query:

```
select path from tree where path <@ 'a.b.c';
```

Result:

[image]

Expected result:

All the below node of a.b.c (In result don't needed a.b.c)

Comment: What is the datatype of `path`?

Comment: It's  ltree type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about explicitly excluding the exact value?

```
select path 
from tree 
where path <@ 'a.b.c' and path <> 'a.b.c'
```

Comment: Thanks, It's  getting expected result

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use:

```
select path 
from tree
where path ~ 'a.b.c.*{1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use:

`select path from tree where path ~ 'a.b.c.*{1,}'`